# Below code in javascript giving two alerts?

Tags: javascript

The below code gives me two alerts one after the other - Hello1234 and undefined

```
var b ={ status:"Ready" ,
         deep : { a:12 , b:"String" ,
                  c:function() {alert("Hello1234");
                               }
                 }  
        }

alert(b.deep.c());
```

Could anyone let me know why does that happen ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @AlexK. No, as it does not return anything explicitly, it returns the `undefined` value implicitly, and the string representation of that is `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because:

1. `b.deep.c()` has a call to `alert` inside it.
2. the return value of that method is not defined, but you attempt to `alert` the return value, so get [the string representation of undefined] `undefined`.

Comment: The return value of `b.deep.c()` is the `undefined` value, which has string representation `"undefined"`.

Comment: @PointedEars - That was what was meant by "the return value of that method is not defined"

Comment: `undefined` is *not* equivalent to "not defined". `undefined` is a value in these languages, the sole value of the `Undefined` type. When that value is converted to `String` by `window.alert()`, the result is the primitive string value `"undefined"`.

Comment: @PointedEars - any variable that is declared but not initialized is initialized to `undefined`.  Any function that reaches end of control without a return statement returns `undefined`.  So in this case, not defined actually _is_ equivalent to `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you @FrankieTheKneeMan, couldnt have explained it better.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan I am well aware of what the `undefined` value is. Exactly *because* of that it is *wrong* to say that the return value of the function is "not defined". See also my answer.

Comment: @PointedEars - you're splitting hairs. If you do not define something, it is undefined!

Comment: @Jamiec Not in ECMAScript. The program `x` will throw a `ReferenceError` exception (even though it is *syntactically* valid), while the program `var x` will happily run and have a global `x` variable (a property of the Global Object) initialized with the `undefined` value. If you would subject `x` to a `typeof` test (`typeof x`), the result would be `"undefined"` *regardless* whether there is an `x` variable or not. So it is important to know the difference between "not defined" and `undefined`.

Comment: @Jamiec For a perhaps better example, `typeof o.x === "undefined"` both for `o === {}` and `o === {x: void 0}`.  In the latter case, `o.x` has clearly been defined, and it still has the `undefined` value. Because it was *initialized* with that *value*.

Comment: @PointedEars Yes, but the answer contains no mention that "everything is undefined" - it merely states that "the return value of the method is not defined", which _definitionally makes it_ `undefined`.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan That is a possible interpretation, but I still find the wording misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Because you call `alert()` two times: Once inside of `c()` and then again with the result of `c()`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want "Hello.." as value
Try following:

```
var b ={ status:"Ready" ,
         deep : { a:12 , b:"String" ,
                  c:function() {return "Hello1234";
                               }
                 }  
        }

alert(b.deep.c());
```

Answer (score 0):

`c` returns nothing alertable so you get `undefined`, return something:

```
var b ={ status:"Ready" ,
         deep : { a:12,
                  b:"String" ,
                  c:function() {
                     alert("Hello1234"); 
                     return "ALERT ME";
                  }
                 }  
        }

alert(b.deep.c());​
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted when it's correct?

Comment: @Zar Because it is *not* correct. The reason why "undefined" is alerted is *because* something "alertable" is returned. In fact, *everything* is generally "alertable" as there is a string representation for *each* value. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

The function `c` does not return any value, so when you call `alert(c())` it executes `c` (which alerts "Hello1234") and then alerts the return value - `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty-printed, that is:

```
var b = {
  status: "Ready",
  deep: {
    a: 12,
    b: "String",
    c: function () {
      alert("Hello1234");
    }
  }  
};

alert(b.deep.c());
```

At first, you are initializing the variable `b` with a reference to an `Object` instance. That object is initialized with own `status` and `deep` properties.  The `deep` property is initialized with a reference to another `Object` instance. That other object is initialized with properties `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Property `c` is initialized with a reference to an anonymous `Function` instance (one without a name).  `Function` instances are callable objects.

In the second step, you are calling the `alert()` method (which should be `window.alert(…)` instead).  You are passing that method the *return value* of the function that the `c` property refers to.

This calls that function,

```
function () {
  alert("Hello1234");
}
```

(in pseudocode) which itself has an

```
  alert("Hello1234");
```

call in it.  So `alert()` is called and "Hello1234" is displayed first.

Then the function that made that `alert()` call ends, because there are no more statements.  The function is *not explicitly* returning a value (with the `return` statement), so it *implicitly* returns the `undefined` value, of the `Undefined` type.

We are now back in the initial `alert()` call.  The return value of `b.deep.c()` is the `undefined` value, so

```
alert(b.deep.c());
```

is evaluated to

```
alert(undefined);
```

But `alert()`, designed to display text messages, expects a `String` value.  Therefore, it performs a *type conversion* from `Undefined` to `String`.

Each value in ECMAScript implementations has a *string representation*.  The string representation of the `undefined` value is `"undefined"`, so

```
alert(String(undefined));
```

is evaluated to

```
alert("undefined");
```

Which is why the second alert box shows "undefined".  You can see that for yourself if you step through the program using a script debugger, such as the built-in [Chrome/Chromium debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) for Mozilla-based browsers like Firefox.